# Captcha replacement

Tags: ajax, captcha

I stumbled upon http://www.kettletime.com.au/chance where the user needs to drag and drop a box with a number into another box to prove that he is human.

How do you implement this? Any free library to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you repost the reference, it is broken?

Comment: @vgv8 no I can't repost the reference, but basically it's just drag and drop like the one in http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be this one: http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin.

> How do you implement this?

Of course, you can implement the functionality on your own (see other answers), but this plug-in seems to be highly configurable :)

> Any free library to do this?

Yup, see link above.

Comment: Thanks. As a web user, I quite like this solution.

Comment: @portoalet Personally, I find it problematic that you cannot submit the form with keyboard-only interaction.

Comment: Are you using something like mouseless browsing plugin for firefox, for your browser? I suppose you prefer the captcha alternative that asks question like "what is 5 minus 1"?

Comment: @portoalet No, I just enjoy using the `<tab>` key to navigate through input fields ... and being able to input all information (including the answer to various captcha challenges) using the keyboard :)

Comment: @jensgram, the bots just love to do the same

Comment: Added benefit, since that Capthca is unusable on iOS devices (and I assume most other tablet/smartphone platforms), you'll also keep out those pesky mobile users.

Comment: To eliminate all doubt: I find this type of CAPTCHAs stupid too :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using jQuery library with jquery UI official plug-in.
Here is a demo and code:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at JqueryUI. The have a direct drag and drop implementation.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/